# How to execute Powershell script function with parameter from Node JS?

Tags: node.js, powershell

Am running a node js service which internally calling a PowerShell script to execute few commands. I am providing some parameters to the node js service from postman, and I want to pass them to the PowerShell script so that it will execute based on the parameter provided.

I am trying to pass them to `CmdletBinding` block of the PowerShell, but I am ok if I can pass it outside the block as well.

Nodejs Service:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
const shell = require('shelljs');
const { stdout, stderr } = require("process");

//Varaible Declaration
let dbListQuote = "";

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/health', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request for health service");
    res.send('OK');
});

app.get('/triggerDatabaseBackup', function (req, res) {

    //Validation for both the parameters like 'dbList' & 'target folder'
    if (req.query.DatabaseList != null && req.query.TargetFolder != null && req.query.DatabaseList != "" && req.query.TargetFolder != "") {
        console.log("Required parameters for database back-up are provided");

        //validation for missing "" for the DBList
        if (req.query.DatabaseList.startsWith('"') && req.query.DatabaseList.slice(-1) === '"') {
            // console.log("The double quotes is present");
        }
        else {
            // console.log("The double quotes is missing, updating the value ");
            dbListQuote = '"' + req.query.DatabaseList + '"';
            // console.log("The updated value ", dbListQuote);
        }

        var dbListTemp = dbListQuote.split(",");
        var dbList = dbListTemp.join("\",\"");
        console.log('Request of database backup for', dbList, 'has been triggered sucessfully !!!');
        let executePowerShellCommand = shell.exec('./powerTest.ps1', {'shell': 'powershell.exe'}, (error,stdout,stderr) => {

        })
        res.status(200).json('Success! Database-backup Completed!')
    }
    else {
        console.log("Parameter Missing");
    }

})

var server = app.listen(9045, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Database Automation Service is listening on :", port);
});
```

**PowerShell Script**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $IPAddress = "SQL Server",
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $Username = "LocalUser",
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $Password = "<Password>",
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string[]][AllowNull()][AllowEmptyCollection()] $DatabaseList=@(<dbList>),
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [string] $source_folder = "req.query.TargetFolder"
    #[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [Int32] $QueryTimeout=600
)


$Status  = Get-Service -ComputerName $IPAddress  | where {($_.name -like "MSSQL$*" -or $_.name -like "MSSQLSERVER" -or $_.name -like "SQL Server (*") }
$object = $Status | SELECT Name,Status
Write-Host "Current State Of The SQL Server " $object.Status
Write-Host "List Of database is :" $DatabaseList
Write-Host "Location Provided is :" $source_folder
```

Prameter From Postman:

[image]

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following,

```
let executePowerShellCommand = shell.exec('./powerTest.ps1', {'shell': 'powershell.exe'}, (error,stdout,stderr) => {
```

to

```
let executePowerShellCommand = shell.exec(`./powerTest.ps1 ${arg0} ${arg1}`, {'shell': 'powershell.exe'}, (error,stdout,stderr) => {
```

Pass any number of argument in arg0, arg1....argn. You need to handle it from PowerShell with $args[0],$args[1]...etc